# formatting hash variables in Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

```
<script id="detail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div class='shipping-details'>
    <ul>
      <li><label>Applied:</label>kendo.toString(#= Applied #, "MM-dd-yyyy" )</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

I have a DateTime field in my model which I want to format.  How do you do this in Telrik's 'UI for ASP.NET MVC' and how do you format kendo # variables in general?

'kendo.' is not recognized in the "text/x-kendo-template", #= Applied # is and displays the full DateTime.

Comment: Why don't you try this instead? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-detail-template

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax error.  The kendo. goes inside the # tags.

```
#= kendo.toString(Applied, "MM-dd-yyyy") #
```